# Closing second JFrame in JAVA (Netbeans) - event

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing JFrame event in JAVA - does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960824/closing-jframe-event-in-java-does-not-work)

I have 2 JFrames.
First JFrame is the main window in my program. Second JFrame appears when we click on button. When this second JFrame (called Settings) is visible, first JFrame, main program's window is disabled `setEnabled(false)`. When I'm closing Settings window my main window is not enabled again. Look at my code. I put there directive `setEnabled(true)` so it should work.

```
    FrameSettings.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    FrameSettings.addWindowStateListener( new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont need JDialogs. Have you ever seen something like that "Do you want to close settings? Yes/No" ? Hm? No

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, in a modal JDialog.

Comment: I want just close JDialog and enable  the main Frame.

Comment: You should not disable and re-enable the frame. Use a modal JDialog, which handles that all by itself. Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
FrameSettings.setDefaultCloseOperation(
    javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

And change this:

```
FrameSettings.addWindowStateListener( new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        setEnabled(true);
        FrameSettings.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot use 'this', I have not got reference to mainJFrame becouse this code is inside mainJFrame class. I created a method which do that but still doesn't work

Comment: @user1916866 Oh, I see. I changed my answer, check it out. Maybe this will do it.

Comment: Nope. I think that this code even don't run. I added some stuff inside (creating buttons etc.) and nothing happened. Listener does not even start.

Comment: @user1916866 God golly. I edited it again, here's another possibility.

Comment: still disabled ;( It should work I see it too, but why it doesn't... I tried the same thing with JDialog. Same problem.

Comment: @user1916866 I think I can still help you. I can't answer any more since your question was closed, but if you email me at aaronman8@gmail.com, i'd be glad to help you. I don't want to have a long chat right here though (on the comment thingy), so email me and I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: @user1916866 Yeah, email me the source code at (once again) aaronman8@gmail.com, and I'll have a look at it, try to fix it, then you can look at what code I changed (assuming I manage to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

I'm gonna call the first JFrame class mainView:

```
mainView object=new mainView();
obj.setVisible(true);
```

Also, instead of `setEnabled(false)` while opening the settings JFrame set the mainView visibility to false.

You don't have to disable views.

**[EDIT]**

Your `setEnabled(true)` doesn't work because you're calling JFrame 2 again. To enable JFrame1create an object and then enable it.

```
JFrame1 o=new JFrame1();
o.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hmm I think there is  small missunderstanding. It's my fould. I'll explain more preciesly. My class looks like that: class Communicator { constructor which displays all containers etc and in this constructor we have this Listener }

Comment: Aren't the two Jframes two separate classes?